# Ruby Convert a Java Byte Buffer object to String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, byte, jruby, bytebuffer, jrubyonrails

Hi i am having an object in ruby which is of type Byte ByteBuffer

Object type: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=437 cap=437]

I want to convert/decode this object into String in ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `String.from_java_bytes` extension however it does not take an (optional) offset and length thus first copy the buffer's content into a new `byte[]` array:

```
>> bytes = Java::byte[buffer.limit].new
=> byte[0, 0, 0]@3427b02d
>> buffer.get(bytes)
=> #<Java::JavaNio::HeapByteBuffer:0x3967e60c>
>> bytes
=> byte[102, 111, 111]@3427b02d
>> String.from_java_bytes bytes
```